# How do you determine equilibrium altitude of helium enclosure?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

How does one determine the equilibrium height/altitude of an enclosure of helium, given payload, weight of enclosure, and net lift?  What is the formula that will help calculate roughly at what altitude the enclosure will reach equilibrium with the surrounding atmosphere?

Comment: You say you have net lift but at equilibrium this will be zero. You should be able to work it all out from Archimedes principle: The lift is equal to the mass of the fluid displaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At balance altitude the weight of helium and its container is equal to the weight of displaced air at that level.

Let's assume you let free a semi-deflated balloon, which can potentially get inflated by diminished surrounding air pressure to 100 cubic meters, containing 10 cubic meters of helium weighing at sea level 1.786 kg and your balloon is 4 kg thin plastic, total of 5.786kg.

We need to find out at what altitude the 100 cubic meters of air weighs 5.786 kg.

Hence we need to find at what altitude the atmosphere density is $$5.786/100 = 0.05786$$

By checking International Standard Atmospheric table in Wikipedia [The link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Atmosphere) and very rough curve fitting, we find the balance altitude at, 21000 meters MSL, Stratosphere.

Obviously, the reality is more complicated and requires refined calculations and considering the event's weather forecast.